# Integer Wavelet with Only Positive coefficients

Tags: wavelet

Is there any **Integer Wavelet Transform** which produce only **positive** coefficients?
Currently i'm using Haar wavelet but it produces both positive and negative coefficients.

Comment: What is the meaning of producing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the wavelet by itself, no, because   it is a  zero-mean function (by construction), hence there are positive and negative values.

For wavelet coefficients from data, no, because of linearity: if for some $x$, $W(x)$ is positive, then $W(-x)=-W(x)$ is negative.

Note that for some signal models, with certain multiscale schemes, you could achieve your goal. You can find hereafter two references:

- [Lossless data hiding based on integer wavelet transform](https://doi.org/10.1109/MMSP.2002.1203308)

> In data hiding, pieces of information represented by the data are
>   hidden in the cover media. In some applications, people do care about
>   the cover media. That is, the hidden data and the cover media may be
>   closely related. For this type of data embedding, in addition to
>   perceptual transparency, for some applications such as medical
>   diagnosis and law enforcement, it is desired to invert the marked
>   media back to the original cover media after the hidden data have been
>   retrieved. The marking techniques satisfying this requirement are
>   referred to as lossless, distortion-free or invertible data hiding
>   techniques. From this point of view, it is observed that most of the
>   current digital watermarking algorithms are not lossless.

- [Distortionless data hiding based on integer wavelet transform](https://doi.org/10.1049/el:20021131)

> A novel distortionless image data hiding algorithm based on integer
>   wavelet transform that can invert the stego-image into the original
>   image without any distortion after the hidden data are extracted is
>   proposed. This algorithm hides data into one (or more) middle
>   bit-plane(s) of the integer wavelet transform coefficients in the
>   middle and high frequency subbands. It can embed much more data
>   compared with the existing distortionless data hiding techniques and
>   satisfy the imperceptibility requirement. The image histogram
>   modification is used to prevent greyscales from possible overflowing.
>   Experimental results have demonstrated the validity of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I had difficulties with data hiding in wavelet coefficients...

Comment: The basic problem is after modifying coefficients and applying inverse integer wavelet, i got some negative pixel values. of course there is some tricks for how to not getting negative pixel values, but i was wondering if there was some kind of wavelet that guaranties positive coefficients in transform and its reverse.